# What does ":*" (colon-star) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Looking up how to calculate the factorial of a number I came across this code:

```
(1..5).inject(:*) || 1 # => 120
```

What is the `(:*) || 1` doing?

How does it compare to this line of code `(1..5).inject(1) { |x, y| x * y } # => 120`, which uses `.inject` to achieve similar functionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Colon-star in itself doesn't mean anything in Ruby. It's just a [symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Symbol.html) and you can pass a symbol to the [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method of an enumerable. That symbol names a method or operator to be used on the elements of the enumerable.

So e.g.:

```
(1..5).inject(:*) #=> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120
(1..5).inject(:+) #=> 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 15
```

The `|| 1` part means that if `inject` returns a [falsey](https://gist.github.com/jfarmer/2647362) value, `1` is used instead. (Which in your example will never happen.)

Comment: You can also pass simmilar construct to other methods eg. map, each, ... (1..5).map(&:to_s), you can also read about to_proc method

Answer (score 3):

test.rb:

```
def do_stuff(binary_function)
  2.send(binary_function, 3)
end

p do_stuff(:+)
p do_stuff(:*)
```

$ ruby test.rb

> 5
>
> 6

If you pass a method name as a symbol, it can be called via send. This is what inject and friends are doing.

About the `||` part, in case the left hand side returns nil or false, `lhs || 1` will return 1

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely equal. You may use each way, up to your taste.

Comment: Not exactly equal in statement, as the `||` 1 is not ever used.  The right hand side is always true.